# Create AWS Transcoder job from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I've created a Lambda function that is called with every new s3 object creation. I'm trying to retrieve the object, then create a new Transcoder job that alters the video quality. But the transcoder job is never created. `creating job....` shows up but `job created` never appears in my logs.

Going off of [this](https://tonym.us/using-aws-lambda-for-web-video-transcoding.html) tutorial.

My Lambda Function:

```
 var aws = require('aws-sdk');
 var elastictranscoder = new aws.ElasticTranscoder();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    console.log('Got Video:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    
    // Get the object from the event and show its content type
    var key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
    console.log('Key:', key);
    var params = {
       Input: { 
          Key: key
       },
       PipelineId: 'xxx', 
       OutputKeyPrefix: 'output/',
       Outputs: [
        {
           Key: outputKey(basename(key),'mp4'),
           PresetId: '1441222625682-nnthmh', // h264
        },
      {
         Key: outputKey(basename(key),'webm'),
         PresetId: '1441222599518-vt9jbu', // webm
        }
      ]
    };

    console.log('creating job....');

    elastictranscoder.createJob(params, function(err, data) {
       console.log('job created');
       if (err){
         console.log('ERROR...',err, err.stack); // an error occurred
         context.fail();
         return;
       }else{
         console.log('created job successfully');
       }
       context.succeed();
    });
};
```

---

I thought it might have something to do with my Lambda role but I'm pretty sure every thing is good. Cloud and transcoder: `createJob` access.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
       "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
           "logs:CreateLogGroup",
           "logs:CreateLogStream",
           "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
  "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
  },
   {
     "Effect": "Allow",
       "Action": [
         "s3:GetObject",
         "s3:PutObject"
        ],
    "Resource": [
       "arn:aws:s3:::*"
     ]
  },
  {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "elastictranscoder:Read*",
            "elastictranscoder:List*",
            "elastictranscoder:*Job",
            "elastictranscoder:CreateJob",
            "elastictranscoder:*Preset",
            "s3:List*",
            "sns:List*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
   ]
 }
```

---

**EDIT**
Changed to [this](http://fartashh.github.io/post/serverless-approach-to-transcode-media/) tutorial. Heres the new code

```
 'use strict';
 console.log('Loading function');

 let aws = require('aws-sdk');
 let s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });
 let elastictranscoder = new aws.ElasticTranscoder();


 function getFileName(path) {
     return path.split('/').reverse()[0].split('.')[0];
 }


 exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
   //  const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
     const key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));

     var params = {
          Input: { 
          Key: key
     },
     PipelineId: 'xxx', 
     OutputKeyPrefix: 'files/',
     Outputs: [
         {
             Key: getFileName(key),
             PresetId: '1351620000001-200060', // hls
        }
         ]
     };
     console.log('loading transcoder');
     elastictranscoder.createJob(params, function(err, data) {
         console.log('made job');
         if (err){
             console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
             context.fail();
             return;
         }
         context.succeed();
     });
 };
```

In the logs I get

> Loading function
>
> START RequestId: xxx Version: $LATEST
>
> loading transcoder
>
> END RequestId: xxx
>
> REPORT RequestId: xxx
>
> Task timed out after 3.00 seconds

The create job block is never called.

Comment: Can you post your Lambda log without sensitive details? Also I have used the code from [this tutorial](http://fartashh.github.io/post/serverless-approach-to-transcode-media/) and with some adjustments worked.

Comment: @manuel changed my code to that tutorial. Still nothing happens

Comment: Does the role have permissions to create a Elastic Transcoder job? With the code from my tutorial should have worked or at least given you a more clear error log.

Comment: @manuel Yes, my role permissions are above. Including createJob permissions.

Comment: @manuel I added a `Bucket` to input param, with the event bucket name. Although this is wrong and I get an error, I do get a log "made job" which is inside the transcoder create job block. With just key in input params, "made job" never gets called

Comment: Did you place the Lambda function inside a VPC that doesn't have a NAT Gateway? If so, you should probably move it out of the VPC since you don't appear to be doing anything that would require VPC access.

Answer (score 0):

Under the VPC drop down i had to choose "No VPC" for this to work - i.e. let it run inside the "default system-managed VPC", once I changed that they worked instantly.

Comment: "No VPC" literally means no VPC. It doesn't mean "default VPC". Lambda functions can't access resources outside a VPC unless the VPC has a NAT Gateway. This is because Lambda functions inside a VPC don't get a public IP address.