# Bad to stream videos with just a url (.mp4 format) - IOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, http-live-streaming

Right now I'm simply storing original videos in S3 and creating an `AVPlayer` with an asset to the url.

```
NSURL *url = 
[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xxxx.cloudfront.net/xxx.mp4"]];
```

I've tried to create an automated AWS Transcoder that turns the videos into a collection of HLS segments and manifest files....which is what you're suppose to do I believe according to apple. But I've looked through multiple tutorials and even posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39277782/create-aws-transcoder-job-from-lambda) but still can not get it working.

Is it bad to have multiple users streaming these videos without HLS segments and .ts files.

Answer (score -2):

You could use Amazon Elastic Transcoder.

FAQ: https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/faqs/

> To use Amazon Elastic Transcoder you need to have at least one media file in an Amazon S3 bucket. The easiest way to use Amazon Elastic Transcoder is to try it through the console. Create a transcoding pipeline that connects the input Amazon S3 bucket to the output Amazon S3 bucket. Create a transcoding job that will transcode your media file, choose a transcoding preset (a template), and submit the job. Your transcoded file will appear in your output bucket once it has been processed.
>
> We support the following video codecs: H.264, VP9, VP8, MPEG-2, and animated GIF. File formats supported include MPEG-2 TS container (for HLS), fmp4 (for Smooth Streaming and MPEG-DASH), MP4, WebM, FLV, MPG, and MXF (XDCAM-compatible). For information on file formats that are supported by specific codecs, please visit the Product Details page.

This tutorial shows has several screenshots to setup the Amazon Elastic Transcoder and how to integrate it with a free JWPlayer. https://www.jwplayer.com/blog/encoding-hls-with-amazon-elastic-transcoder/

The player embed would look something like this.

```
<video height="270" width="480" controls
  poster="http://d3mk7n3cl27pjb.cloudfront.net/bigbuckbunny/bunny-00004.png"
  src src="http://d1s3yn3kxq96sy.cloudfront.net/bigbuckbunny/index.m3u8">
  <p>Your browser does not support HLS playback in HTML5.</p>
</video>
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Understood. Updated. Not sure if was worth negative votes though.